# How adjust tolerance level for OpenCV detection false positives?

Tags: java, opencv, video

I'm developing a system using OpenCV, which detects objects with the haarCascades xml files. However, there are many false detections. There is a way to minimize false detections? This is part of my code:

```
private void detecta(String arquivo)
{
CascadeClassifier bodyDetector = new CascadeClassifier(path+arquivo);
 MatOfRect faceDetections = new MatOfRect();
    bodyDetector.detectMultiScale(webcam_image, faceDetections);
       // bodyDetector.detectMultiScale(webcam_image, faceDetections);

    for (Rect rect : faceDetections.toArray()) {
      Core.rectangle(webcam_image, new Point(rect.x, rect.y), new Point(rect.x +         rect.width, rect.y + rect.height), new Scalar(0, 255, 0));// mat2Buf, mat2Buf);
    }

    if (faceDetections.toArray().length == 0) {

      toc.getLblSaida().setText("");

    } else {

      //java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();  
      toc.getLblSaida().setText(+faceDetections.toArray().length + "objetos detectados");
  try {
      playSound();
  } catch (IOException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(TestWebCam.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

there's a couple of overloads to [detectMultiScale](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/objdetect/CascadeClassifier.html#detectMultiScale(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.MatOfRect,%20double,%20int,%20int,%20org.opencv.core.Size,%20org.opencv.core.Size)) that will allow you to do this.

i.e increasing the value for minNeighbours [needed for a valid detection], and setting minSize and maxSize will probably achieve, what you want.

Comment: Thanks for helping! I tried your tip. I did as follows: bodyDetector.detectMultiScale(webcam_image, faceDetections,1.1, 4, 0, new Size(20,20), new Size());
But, yet I have false detections...

Comment: try to increase minNeighbours, until you start to miss positives